# How to find all the "user defined functions" from ELF and PE file?

Tags: c, assembly, elf, libc

test platform is on 32 bit Linux and Windows.

I am trying to identify all the user defined functions towards dynamic linked binary,

extracting their instructions and assemble them into binary again.

As for the ELF file, I use this:

```
nm binary | grep "T"
```

to extract certain functions, and I consider all the functions who don't begin with **_** should be the user defined functions.

It works fine for small programs...

But when I am testing coreutils (8.5), for example like basename

Here is part of the output of **nm**

```
0804b530 T rpl_fflush
0804b590 T rpl_fseeko
0804a400 T set_char_quoting
0804a480 T set_custom_quoting
08049580 T set_program_name
0804a460 T set_quoting_flags
0804a3e0 T set_quoting_style
08049480 T strip_trailing_slashes
08048f70 T usage
0804b0f0 T version_etc
0804b6c0 T atexit
```

In the source code of **basename**, it only defines three functions as

```
main
usage
remove_suffix
```

But I use nm to find lots of functions here...

Basically I think these functions like **version_etc** **atexit** are defined in the header files 
basename included

So my question is :

How to accurately find all the user defined functions from a ELF file?

Any answers on PE file is also welcomed!

THank you!

Comment: The ELF file contains all the functions that were linked into it, including stuff included from static libraries that got linked in. The only chance you have at doing what you want is looking at debug information contained in the ELF and guessing.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically I think these functions like `version_etc` `atexit` are defined in the header files `basename` included

Your mental model of how `basename` is built appears to be completely incorrect.

`basename` is built from `basename.o` *and* a whole bunch of other objects (which are part of `coreutils`) *and* a whole bunch more objects pulled in from other libraries.

Once `basename` is linked, there is no way to tell which functions came from where.

Besides, what does "user defined function" even mean?

Comment: Hi, basically I am trying to reassemble the disassembled asm file into binary. I am stucked in the link step now... What I am trying to do is to select all the functions **not** in the libc, assembly it, and use gcc to link the obj file with libc.

Comment: And as for the "user defined function", I mean functions found in the disassembled file, and **not** in the libc

Comment: I am thinking that, as the binary is dynamic linked, so all the functions found in the disassembled file should be "user defined functions" But in the disassembled file, I found functions like "rpl_fflush" "atexit", which is not in the basename.c file, so I think they should be in the included head files